# DSL to describe (and maybe render) tech trees?

Tags: gui, visualization

Are there any open-source instruments with easy-to-write (maybe YAML-like) syntax which allow to describe tech tree in text file and (preferably) render it by some diagram engine like graphml(yEd) or graphviz?

I tried to use WYSIWYG diagram editors (yEd) for this. But I find very frustrating to edit *tech trees* in such programs since you need to repeatly type in labels like "cost:/effect:" or scroll over multiple lines to change tech cost, for example. I want to see and edit tech tree data in a plaintext form which is most convenient for me (kind-of software engineer and computer geek, eh)

Not sure this is suitable SE community for such question but don't know where to ask it anyway.

Comment: *"I find very frustrating to edit tech trees in such programs since you need to repeatly type in labels like "cost:/effect:""* - what else do you want to be displayed, do you have an example pic?

Comment: Is the tech tree a [Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) or a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is cross-posted on another stack echange site, which is not allowed.